# Delete a file from a branch and commit it back to the master in Github/Git?

Tags: git, github

The scenario is this - on a branch, code from a few files has been combined into a single file. The original files are no longer needed and deleted from the branch. Will the same happen to the master when merging the committed branch back in?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have deleted the files locally and will push that local branch to the remote branch, then **YES**. The files at remote origin will also get deleted.

Also, you'll need to commit the deleted files locally and only then push.

Let me know if this is what you are intending to do.

Comment: Yes that is my intention. Thanks!

Comment: @JayJ: Then would you be kind enough to accept the answer as correct :)

Comment: Yes. about 5 more minutes have to pass before SO allows me to do that. Otherwise I would have accepted it already. If you think I asked a good question could you vote it up? :)

Comment: @JayJ: You'll need to commit the deleted files locally also and then push.

Comment: Ok. I figured but I'm glad you explicitly mentioned it. Please feel free to amend that in your answer.